# Is there any way to know which which part of the file are still in the Physical RAM after it was read by some process

Tags: windows, winapi, file, filesystems

Lets say I used a program that read a file and that the program was finished. Now ,
most likely that parts of the file still reside in the physical ram (lets assume I have huge amount of RAM).

Is there any way to know which parts of the file reside in the physical ram? Is there any tool that can do it or maybe a winapi function call?

Comment: Which RAM?  Processor cache?  L2 Cache?  Main memory?  I/O bus cache?  Disk controller cache?  Which one(s) do you want to know about?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is the information in the file sensitive and you want to erase all traces of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points to remember:

1. You never have direct access to physical RAM. The OS gives you an abstraction of RAM. It may be physical RAM, or virtual memory paged away on some hard disk. You can never know.
2. Even if some bits remain stashed away in some part of the RAM (physical or otherwise), the OS sees that memory block as free (unless it has already been taken again). I doubt you can get access to it without hacking the OS somehow.

Let me clarify my point in regards to your comment:

Let's assume you opened a file, read it to RAM, did some stuff with it, and closed the file, and your program has terminated. First, I think we all agree that the portion of RAM you used is no longer taken, and is considered free by the OS. Meaning another program that comes along and demands some RAM might receive that memory block. So, first of all, **nothing resides in that memory block anymore**. It's empty. Free for the OS to use at its discretion.

Now, even if some random bits of data are left hanging around (remember, you have no way of knowing if it's physical or otherwise), you have no direct access to them.

I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Jon Skeet might disagree on this point. He can probably hack your RAM remotely with the help of a coal-powered calculator ;P

Comment: thanks for the answer. But read carefuly my question. I don't want a direct access to the RAM , I just want to know which files (or part of them) reside in the ram.

Comment: @yossi1981: Which RAM?  There are many, many pieces of RAM in a modern processor, which ones are you asking about?

Comment: Not actually true for Windows (NT series). They've got **two** free lists, one zeroed and one not yet zeroed. Any page allocated for your process will be zeroed before you get it, so you won't get any data from another process.

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about Windows, the content will be in Windows file cache.

there's no tool/API to read Windows file cache now.

However, you can read all contents in your physical memory by a special name like CreateFile('\\.\PhysicalMemory') or the name \Device\PhysicalMemory.  (note: only works on XP/2000)

Answer (score 0):

*> there's no tool/API to read Windows file cache now.*

Of course there are apis (Win32 st) !